# How to hide a container when a button is clicked and make a form appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wakanda

So I'm trying to make a store for computers and I'm making a webshop for it, but I ran into a problem.

Now I have a container, and I want it to hide it's content when i click a button, and then a form needs to appear with name, email and a textrea for what they want to buy..
but if they click anywhere on  page, other then the button I want to bring the old content back!

I'm building this in a program called Wakanda Studios, i don't know if this helps, but I'm sure someone will find my answer.

Quick note: I don't have any code yet, other then my container!

Comment: Learn some coding first

Comment: Show us your effort we shall help you ..... you want others to code for you then please hire someone ... there are various freelancers available

Comment: `$(button).click(function(){
        $(container).hide();
        $(form).show();
    }`

Comment: @Vicky look, no offence, but why hire a freelancer for $50 when I only need help? I don't know code but people like you do, and I've done my fair share of helping people (in the real world), so instead of giving a "proof yourself" you could also try to help me! again, no offence.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it is written in jQuery so you will have to add jQuery to your page by putting
 `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the document head and then adding the following code at the end of your page...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-id").click(function(){ 
        $("#container-id").hide(); 
        $("#form-id").show(); 
    });
    $(document).click(function(){
        $("#container-id").show();
        $("#form-id").hide();
    });
});
```

All you will have to now is add the ID attribute to the button which starts everything off, the container, and the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the WAF framework of Wakanda and Studio, you would select your button, go to the events tab and add an on click event.

This will stub in a wrapper for the code to execute on click.

To hide a container, you need the container id. Using this you create a Wakanda reference to the widget and use the "hide()" method.

```
$$('yourContainerId').hide();
```

JQuery would work as well.